# Счётная форма существительного

Tags: грамматика, падежи, числительные, множественное-число

Сейчас часто можно встретить рекомендации использовать так назыаемую счетную форму (давайте для примера рассматривать словосочетание «20 байт(-ов)»). На этом всячески [настаивает Справка Грамоты.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%F1%F7%E5%F2%ED%E0%FF+%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0), а другие источники обычно на неё ссылаются. Кроме того, я наткнулся на [статью](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/krysin-04c.htm), в которой со ссылкой на «Орфоэпический словарь 1989» говорится:

> Современный "Орфоэпический словарь русского языка" вводит понятие счетной формы <…>, которое актуально для названий единиц измерения - существительных мужского рода с основами на твердый согласный.
>   При указании количества какой-либо энергии или физической величины
>   формы типа *5 вольт*, *10 ампер*, *100 ватт* являются **нормативными**; наряду с
>   ними возможны и формы с флексией *-ов*.

*(выделение полужирным моё)*

Я уж подумал, что всё однозначно и следует использовать форму «20 байт», но не тут-то было. Институт Виноградова [считает (сообщение № 22)](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=2669&0a1=t&0p1=60&0y1=2008&0r1=False), что:

> По данным "Русского орфографического словаря" (М., 2005), кроме
>   обычной формы родительного падежа - *битов*, *байтов*, *килобайтов* -
>   существует счетная форма, которая используется в сочетании с
>   числительными: *8 байт*, *16 килобайт*. Счетная форма является
>   **разговорной**.

*(выделение полужирным опять моё)*

Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут очевидно же, что зависит от смысла: используется родительный падеж или счетный. Если говорится о конкретных объектах, то это родительный падеж. Если об абстрактной величине, то счетный.

Например:

> Это устройство передаёт пять байт в секунду
>
> Мне эти пять байтов испортили карьеру

Answer (score 0):

Аркадий Мильчин в своём Справочнике издателя и автора пишет о количественных числительных:

> В изданиях для массового читателя рекомендуется в подобных случаях
>   отказываться не от словесно-цифровой формы чисел, а от сокращённых
>   обозначений единиц величин - заменять их полными наименованиями.
>   *Напр.: 20 миллионов километров, 500 тысяч вольт* (6.1. Количественные
>   числительные, с. 142).

У Артемия Лебедева есть [статья о байтах](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/84/).

В связи с этим статью в Википедии о счётной форме я бы посчитала валидной:

> Счётная фо́рма — в русском языке особая форма множественного числа
>   существительных, употребляемая в сочетании с численными обозначениями
>   количества чего-либо.
>
> Например: восемь бит, двести пятьдесят шесть байт, пять килограмм (или
>   килограммов). Но: количество байтов, избавиться от лишних
>   килограммов.
>
> Для некоторых слов нет счётной формы, в таком случае для них
>   используется обычная форма родительного падежа множественного числа:
>   пять метров, десять литров.

Comment: У Лебедева статья вообще не об этом. Я там даже нигде на нашел примера, в котором могла бы быть счетная форма. Что касается Википедии, то это вообще очень сомнительный источник, поскольку, во-первых, они ссылаются на ту самую Грамоту, во-вторых, [они сами не уверены](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82).

Comment: Что касается Мильчина, то он ведь тоже не об этом пишет, хотя пример со счетной формой «вольт», конечно, присутствует. Справочник этот несомненно очень хорош, но всё-таки я не нашел там конкретных рекомендаций именно по сути моего вопроса. Тут ведь вопрос, всё-таки, не об оформлении, а о грамматике, так что этот справочник мне не видится достаточно авторитетным источником в данном случае.

Comment: Мильчин пишет не об этом, но употребляет именно такую форму. Лебедев тоже. Мильчин в своем справочнике не стал бы употреблять неправильную форму.

Comment: Справедливости ради замечу, что нашел у Лебедева примеры, где он использует счетную форму.

Comment: Я точно так же могу сказать «Институт Виноградова (кстати, со ссылкой на словарь 2005-го года, в то время как Мильчин писал справочник несколько раньше) не стал бы врать, что эта форма — разговорная».

Answer (score 0):

Мне как носителю кажется, что дело в том, что байты — это не количество энергии или физической величины, а объекты, которые могут восприниматься как по отдельности, так и в совокупности. Совокупность проявляется ярче, когда используются приставки кратности. 5 байтов — это допустимо, а 5 килобайтов — уже режет ухо.

Химики измеряют количество вещества в молях, но с тем же успехом могли бы измерять в иоттамолекулах или иоттаатомах. При этом 5 атомов — это допустимо, а 5 иоттаатомов — нет.